# Adding hyphens to regex string returns 0 results-MongoDB

Tags: regex, mongodb

I'm currently running a query on MongoDB, the field I'm querying contains values such as `123245123 - Johnson-Perez`. If I build a query such as `{"name":/123245123/ix}` I get tons of rows and that's fine, however, as soon as you add the hypens `{"name":/123245123 - Johnson-Perez/ix}` I get 0 rows. Do you guys know what could be causing this? I've tried replacing the hyphens with `[-]` and putting the entire string in double quotes but it didn't work. I have zero knowledge on regex so I don't know what could be causing this.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
{"name":/^[0-9]* - [A-Zaz]*$/ix}
```

Comment: Nope, 0 rows :(

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, I have to escape the whitespaces as well as the hyphen and the dots.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).